# PHP: Can I guarantee that date('s') will always return an unique value?

Tags: php, datetime

Pardon me if something wrong in this question. May be it's a very dumb question but need to know exactly.

```
$t = date('s'); // s for second
echo mkTime($t); // 1335629750
```

Will the above code always return an unique number, I thought it'll return me current timestamp (only second) and that is going to be unique for every users, am I wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: No, you cannot guarantee it will be unique.

Comment: You could have easily figured this out by looking up the function in the php docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: Your code takes the seconds from the current time (e.g. `30` for `2012-04-28 05:24:30`). This number is then fed into the `$hour` parameter for [`mktime()`](http://php.net/mktime).  No, it will not always return a unique number… not even nearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just using `time()` will suffice to get the current timestamp
2. Timestamps are not unique per user and cannot be depended upon to be a unique value as multiple users can get the same timestamp if called concurrently

Answer (score 2):

No, the current timestamp is not unique. If you need something unique, use PHP's function [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). It generates a unique identifier based on the current time in microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you are calling it multiple times the same second (in the same script or on two different requests) it won't be unique.

Answer (score 1):

yes, what the script runs twice in the same second? It's not really impossible at all. So you are NOT guaranteed AT ALL to get a unique number. If you need something unique, create a (semi-)random number, save every used number in a database/datafile and check if the number is used before every time.